# Correct pronunciation of 'Chez Albert': is there a liaison?

Tags: prononciation, noms-propres, liaisons

I had a little dispute yesterday on what the correct pronunciation of 'chez Albert' is. In my understanding, I would pronounce the latent 'z' of 'chez' because the next word starts with a vowel (liaison). My friend on the other hand argued that in this case the 'z' stays silent.

**What is the correct pronunciation of the phrase 'chez Albert'?**

If this is an exception to the liaison rule, is there a reason for this being an exception?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no single "liaison rule" in French but a gazillion of small scope "liaison rules" each one often with exceptions.

Here is [what the TLFI says](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chez) about "z" liaisons:

> c) Liaison. Cf. Kamm. 1964, p. 238 : ,,La lettre [z] peut se lier
>   (devant voyelle). En réalité, elle se trouve rarement en situation
>   d'être liée. On ne voit vraiment que les deux mots chez, assez et les
>   formes verbales. **Si la liaison est obligatoire dans allez-y, elle est
>   facultative ailleurs.** Ex. : chez autrui [ʃezotʀ ɥi] ou [ʃeotʀ ɥi];
>   assez˘important ou assez/important; vous˘irez˘à l'école ou vous˘irez/à
>   l'école``. On peut ajouter que gén. la liaison se fait. Cf. Fouché
>   Prononc. 1959, p. 477. Cf. aussi la rem. ds Fér. 1768, Fér. Crit. t. 1
>   1787, Land. 1834, Gattel 1841, Littré et Dub. Ex. : chez eux [ʃezø],
>   chez elle [ʃezεl]. **Par contre le plus souvent on ne fait pas la
>   liaison devant un n. propre.** On entend plus fréquemment [ʃeãdʀe] que
>   [ʃezãdʀe] pour chez André.

I never made or heard the liaison in "Chez Albert" so I would say the liaison is at best very improbable in this case, just like "Chez Antoine".

On the other hand, the liaison is extremely common in "Chez eux" and in "Chez elle" but nevertheless stated as optional by the TLFI. You can definitely hear people saying "C'est chez lui ou chez elle ?" with no liaison in "chez elle", same with "chez un ami".

Comment: I have never heard any French speaking people say  *ʃeø* or *ʃel*, so I would say the liaison is more than "common".

Comment: @Laure You probably didn't notice it but I'm almost sure you have already heard "Chez elle" without a liaison.

Comment: @jlliagre I heard it, but exclusively from films/series/shows when the on-screen people are mocking a kind of person with limited vocabulary. But in real life? I never heard it.

Comment: @ogregoire Listen closer to people around you. Sometimes the brain is filtering out things you don't want to listen...

Comment: If someone asks one question, must we put up all the rules for all elisions in French. And no, chez elle is always elided. The term liaison is elision in English....so to answer the question, yes, Chez Albert is elided.

Comment: @Lambie As far as I understand, "elision" is literally the opposite of "liaison" and there's no word (other than a French loanword) for "liaison" in English.

Comment: @Lambie: no, *elision* and *liaison* both exist and are two different concepts.

Answer (score 14):

L'exemple donné soulève deux questions :

1. La liaison après **chez** : elle est [obligatoire](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3549)* :

> La liaison est aussi obligatoire entre une préposition ne comportant
>   qu’une syllabe et le mot qui suit.

Exemple :
Elles rentrent chez elles [ʃezɛl] / elle rentre chez elle [ʃezɛl].

2. La liaison avec les **noms propres** : certains la jugent interdite mais de fait certains francophones font la liaison avec les noms propres, et elle reste du domaine des liaisons facultatives.

*Voir aussi : http://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/liaisons_obligatoires_liaisons_interdites.htm
and for English speakers: http://www.spellandsound.com/french-liaisons/#requiredliaison

Comment: For English speakers, the word is elisions. Liaisons are dangerous. :)

Comment: @Lambie Isn't elision literally the opposite of "liaison"...? "Elision" means omitting something, with a liaison you add a sound.

Comment: @Lambie "Liaison"  is the word used in linguistics for the "the pronunciation of a latent word-final consonant immediately before a following vowel sound". English doesn't have liaisons and the word is borrowed from the French. Elision is the omission of a sound (as in *doesn't*).

Comment: Ce qui est très bizarre, c'est qu'elle est obligatoire seulement quand c'est un pronom. Elle rentre chez elle. Mais quand il s'agit d'un nom propre, elle devient interdite. Elle rentre chez Alice.

Answer (score 4):

Il est vrai que l'on dit: « Chez eux » en faisant la liaison. 
De même on dit « je vais chez un ami » en faisant aussi la liaison.
Mais pour Albert, je ne ferais pas la liaison ! Peut-être parce qu'il s'agit d'un prénom, car je ne dirais pas non plus « je vais chez'Elodie » !
Ce sont les bizarreries de la langue française !

Comment: Ce ne sont pas des _bizarreries_, mais bien une manière justement d'assurer la compréhension du nom qui n'est pas commun. Il s'agit d'expliquer, plutôt que de commenter. Merci.

Answer (score 3):

En appui aux réponses précédentes, il peut y avoir des nuances dans l'emploi de la liaison selon le registre (oral vs. lecture/soigné) et la région. D'autre part, [elle](http://www.bertrandboutin.ca/Folder_151_Grammaire/A_e_la_liaison.htm) est « généralement considérée comme [**obligatoire**](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17712) [...] [e]ntre les prépositions monosyllabiques et leur régime. » ; aussi souvent avec *avant/devant* + eux/elle(s) (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. *Duculot*, 14<sup>e</sup>, § 43 5°).

Par ailleurs, un phénomène comme la [*disjonction*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Prononciation/fran%C3%A7ais/disjonction) pourrait s'y opposer, car dans un tel cas la voyelle du mot qui suit la préposition se comporte un peu comme une consonne phonétiquement, et donc l'élision et la liaison cessent. Il y a une « certaine tendance », qui n'est pas récente (déjà au 17<sup>e</sup>), avec *que* (mais aussi avec *de* ; *de Ingres*), à faire la disjonction devant un *nom propre de personne*, comme on l'a [remarqué](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17711), a fortiori s'il est *court*, qu'il a des *homophones*, ou une consonance étrangère (LBU14, § 50 f). Et donc cette tendance pourrait peut-être expliquer un usage ici avec *chez*. Enfin on n'a pas mentionné le contexte du nom d'entreprise, possiblement dans le sens de la disjonction (chez *Albert et fils inc.* ; difficile d'imaginer la liaison si l'objectif est la prononciation intégrale du nom, quoiqu'on puisse imaginer un usage se développer).

---

Il y a possiblement antagonisme entre le phénomène de *liaison* en général et la tendance à la *disjonction* devant le *nom propre*, qui en annulerait l'effet...

Answer (score 3):

For liaison, it's helpful if you remember that the writing reflects the spoken language, and not the other way around.

So, hundreds of years ago, when the z in chez was pronounced in all contexts, one would say che/z/ lui, che/z/ elle, etc, che/z/ Louis, etc, all with z pronounced. When final consonants disappeared, they were retained before vowels (because the enchainement process meant the "z" before elle was pronounced as the beginning of a syllable rather than the end of the preceding one).

So if a phrase is relatively "new," we expect it not to take liaison (or only to take liaison in educated contexts), whereas if it's old enough to predate the sound change, we expect it to take liaison. In this case, "chez elle" and "chez eux" are both standard prepositional phrases that one hears all the time; this reinforces that the liaison should take place. By contrast, "Chez Alice" refers to where a specific person Alice lives. Unless Alice was alive when the sound change happened, we don't expect a liaison.

This is also why lots of fixed phrases like "de temps_en temps" take liaison (the "s" was pronounced before "en" when this phrase acquired its fixed meaning), as do standard grammatical constructions "vous_atterrissez." Grammaticalized liaison takes place even before "new" verbs, presumably because the liaison rule is so uniform and internalized in these contexts: "vous_alunissez."

Answer (score 3):

I'm no linguist but I'd say both ways are usable. I personnaly make such liaisons most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

You should always make the liaison with the word "Chez", even if the next vowel-started word is a Proper Name (Nom propre).

Officialy, this liaison is obligatory, but depending where you live *(my Statement is from Canada)*, it's a form of respect to not make the liaison with the name of someone or any identity (like a place, a restaurant, a company name) like Chez Albert.

Comment: What makes you support a rule probably something like 99% of native French speakers do not follow? (chez + proper name).

Comment: As I said, nobody really says chez + name as it is impolite. I'm native, and I don't make a liaison on Chez Albert.

Comment: Having to break a pronunciation rule in order to be polite means the rule is broken. The OQLF should correct its statement about the liaison after a one syllable preposition to match the reality of the French pronunciation.

Comment: @jlliagre Il n'y a pas que le OQLF, il y a aussi Grevisse qui dit que la liaison est obligatoire après un certain nombre de prépositions monosyllabiques (et il en ajoute aussi à plusieurs syllabes).

Comment: @jlliagre Et  aussi http://www.linguistes.com/phonetique/varinterne.html. Ça fait partie des choses que les petits français apprennent dans leur apprentissage orale de la langue (disons qui sont enseignées par l'institution scolaire) et qui sont enseignées de façon systématiques dans l'apprentissage du FLE.

Comment: @Laure Je vois en effet ces sites qui promeuvent une règle qui n'a probablement pour justification que l'objectif de tenter d’homogénéiser la liaison après chez. Pourquoi pas mais les règles de prononciation entérinent généralement l'usage, rarement l'inversent.

Comment: @jlliagre En ce qui concerne l'usage je n'ai personnellement jamais entendu en France (ouest sud et centre) que la liaison se fasse pas après "chez", "dans" et "en" (sauf devant noms propres où elle est parfois omise) et elle est enseignée par l'institution scolaire (par exemple un non francophone qui passe en examen de français est sanctionné s'il ne fait pas la liaison dans "chez eux"). Il est important de distinguer des exceptions et variantes d'une certaine norme qui semble dépasser l'hexagone.

Comment: @Laure Après un rapide sondage dans mon entourage certes trop limité pour être représentatif (région parisienne et marseillaise), la liaison n'est jamais faite dans les expression « Chez Albert » et  « Chez Antoine » et y apparaît comme excessive. Je ne la conteste pas du tout « Chez eux » où je l'ai toujours entendue. Il n'y a en revanche pas de consensus sur la liaison « Je suis allé chez un ami » où les deux formes sont en concurrence.

Comment: Je signale que mon affirmation est dans un contexte Canadien. Je précise bien dans ma réponse que cela risque fortement de varier en fonction de ta région et de ta culture francophone. Sauf que la règle de Français, aussi vieille soit-elle, est de toujours faire la liaison, même si certains ne le font pas pour les Noms Propres pour la raison que j'ai cité dans ma réponse ou pour tout autre raison qu'ils jugent utile.